# how to retain fragments using navigation component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-navigation-graph

I am trying to create a side navigation drawer based app using the latest navigation component library (`'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'`
and `'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'`)
I tried to follow the basic template for creating a nav drawer, but everytime i click a menu item, it destroys the current fragment and creates a new one. also, when pressing back, we go back to start fragment, but the start fragment is also recreated, and is not in the state which it originally was.
So my question is **if it is possible to retain a fragment without causing a repeated destroy/create cycle ?**

I know that the *"state"* of the fragment can be retained using activity viewmodel or save instance state, but at certain times, it would be more beneficial to just use a singleton fragment instead of recreating it. The [following advance navigation sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) from google does retain the navigation state, but my current doesn't seem to be even doing that, why?

code:

```xml
//navgraph sidenav advance.xml

<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <navigation android:id="@+id/nav_home" app:startDestination="@+id/frag_home">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frag_home"
            android:name="work.curioustools.fragmentpracticalsamples.side_navigation.HomeFragment"
            android:label="@string/menu_home"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_side_navigation" />
    </navigation>

    <navigation android:id="@+id/nav_gallery" app:startDestination="@+id/frag_gallary">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frag_gallary"
            android:name="work.curioustools.fragmentpracticalsamples.side_navigation.GalleryFragment"
            android:label="@string/menu_gallery"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_side_navigation" />

    </navigation>

    <navigation android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow" app:startDestination="@+id/frag_slideshow">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frag_slideshow"
            android:name="work.curioustools.fragmentpracticalsamples.side_navigation.SlideshowFragment"
            android:label="@string/menu_slideshow"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_side_navigation" />
    </navigation>
    
</navigation>
```

```xml
activity sidenav default.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                tools:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_sidenav"
                app:title="@string/app_name"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_navhost_default"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/navgraph_sidenav_advance" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
             />


    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:layout_width="100dp"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_side_navigation" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

```kotlin
// activity : SideNavigationDrawerDefaultActivity

class SideNavigationDrawerDefaultActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private  val binding by lazy {  ActivitySideNavigationDefaultBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }
    private  val appBarConfiguration by lazy { AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow), binding.drawerLayout) }
    private  val navController by lazy {
        val navHost = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navhost_default) as NavHostFragment
        navHost.navController
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        //setupActionBar
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        //setup side drawer
        binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
        binding.fab.setOnClickListener { snack("hello",it) }
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create separate nav graph file for each navigation drawer item. Then give same id to both nav graph and the corresponding drawer menu item.

**Nav File for nav_search_new menu:**

```
<navigation 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_search_new"
app:startDestination="@id/newSearchFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/newSearchFragment"
    android:name="com.sequence.main.ui.search.NewSearchFragment"
    android:label="fragment_new_search"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_new_search" />
</navigation>
```

**Menu :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@+id/nav_home_new"
    android:title="@string/home"
    android:icon="@drawable/baseline_home_24"/>

<item android:id="@+id/nav_topic_new"
    android:title="@string/topic"
    android:icon="@drawable/baseline_topic_24"/>

<item android:id="@+id/nav_search_new"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/baseline_search_24"/>
</menu>
```

Finally add all graph in main graph file and set it as navGraph in navHostFragment:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/nav_home_new">
   <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_home_new" />
   <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_topic_new" />
   <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_search_new" />
</navigation>
```